# Traveling to the US on a one-way ticket and returning with a different airline on a separate return ticket

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, proof-of-onward-travel, return-tickets

I have devised a travel itinerary that involves visiting Canada from Europe, then continuing to the US, and finally returning to Europe, all within a span of a maximum of two weeks. To execute this plan, I intend to purchase a multi-city return ticket for the Europe-Canada and US-Europe legs. However, I plan to secure a one-way ticket from Canada to the US using a different airline due to the cost advantage. My concern is whether this arrangement might cause any issues during my entry into the US. I've heard that immigration officers often rely solely on the information provided by the current airline, potentially leading them to believe that I lack a return ticket. Is this a legitimate concern?

Comment: it's certainly legal to do this; just bring a copy of your flight reservations in case you are asked to show them. note that US immigration processing for most flights from Canada happens in the Canadian airport before boarding, so in the extremely unlikely event that you are denied entry to the US, you will be able to simply walk "back into Canada" and make alternate arrangements from there

Comment: I have done precisely this (except in reverse: Europe – US – Canada – Europe) and had no issues at all. As other comments and answers suggest, I had to show my full itinerary of tickets a few times (both when entering the US and when entering Canada, if memory serves), but other than that no problems at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this a legitimate concern?

Not really. There is absolutely no requirement that your exit ticket and entry ticket need to be on the same itinerary or from the same airline. There is a good chance, that you will be asked for the ticket, so you should have print out of it handy: Make sure the print out shows the confirmation number (PNR), dates, and names of all passengers.

It's also likely that the only ones asking will be the airline during check in, not CBP.

This may take a few minutes longer, but if you have decent proof of an exit flight, you should be fine.

Comment: The main difference is that if it is on the same PNR, the airline will already have the info, and CBP probably will have it also, so the chances of either asking are very low. If it's on a different PNR, the airline will want to see it (though probably not here since OP is coming from Canada and will have gone through pre-clearance) and CBP may want to see it.

Comment: The airline will likely want to see your US exit ticket during check in which will always happen in Canada (regardless of whether there is pre-clearance or not). They need to check whether you have proper documentation for travel to the US before they issue a boarding pass. That happened to me travelling to/from Australia with different tickets. The airline did verify our exit ticket but immigration didn't ask for anything presumable since the airline has presumable the info collected at check in to the immigration.